# Without opening an app, how to check if an app is installed in ios device or not from website?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, deep-linking

I want to check if an app is installed in iphone or not from web page using javascript. If app is installed then i want to show "open" button in website, once if user clicks "open" button in website then i have to open an app in iphone by custom url scheme. If app is not installed then i want to show "Download" button in web page. How to do this?

I had tried javascript with setTimeout function which tries to open an app by custom url scheme, but it directly opens an app. Without opening an app, how to check if app is installed.

Comment: Looks like you need the app banner: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Comment: Do you have access to the app's code?

Comment: Yes, i have access to ios app code

Comment: That banner already does that. Read the page I linked.

Comment: I had read the link thanks i got a solution